# how can I pass variable in Express and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to do something with node.js and express . 
but I face some problem in express passing variable to .js

here is my code , I want to know the IP address in the .js , so I do the following things

like this , I redirected the user to the test.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  app.set('ipAddr' , req.ip);
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

and index.html include

```
 <script src="/hello.js"></script>
```

so , in the hello.js , I want to know the client IP address.

I try to find out how to do it , but I fail.

can anyone tell me how to do it ? really thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `IP` of client, can be found at `req.connection.remoteAddress` you can either pass the variable with `res.render` to a page, or use `res.send`

Comment: thanks , but if I use res.render , it can't be redirect to the index.html , if I use res.render , can you give some example to explain how to get the varible from client ?